# No space left on the device when /dev/sda is only at 84%

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, vps

No space left on the device when /dev/sda is only at 84%

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             8182636         0   8182636   0% /dev 
tmpfs            1642508      6372   1636136   1% /run
/dev/sda       330078748 260594596  52704200  84% / 
tmpfs            8212524         0   8212524   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            5120            0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            8212524         0   8212524   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            1642504         0   1642504   0% /run/user/0
```

This is happening on my linode, I should have 40GB+ left but /dev/sda thinks it's full. I can't move regular files but I can make a big file with `dd`. Linode support says that's normal but that can't be right.

Also just to see if the disk was bad I "cloned" the linode and the same problem happens on the new one. Am I missing something?

**Edit** - here's what I was seeing when I tried to do tab completion:

-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device

Comment: [Please do not post images instead of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). Can you add to your post the full output of `df` and a command with its output, where we can see the actual error message?

Comment: There's no good way to format that text which is why I did it that way, but I'll paste it in there... The message is the "no space left on device" message that happens when the disk is full. It's not doing it right now because I moved some files to a new volume.

Comment: Yes, please do, both outputs (`df` and the command that shows the error message). Just paste them and I'll help you format it.

Comment: What is the output of `df -i`?

Comment: @Kamil, `df -i` says /dev/sda is at 100%, that's interesting `/dev/sda       20464000 20463082     918  100% /`

Comment: Please [edit] and put the output of `df -i` in the question body.

Comment: @Kamil I think you solved my problem for me already, thanks. I'm out of inodes.

Comment: @pguardiario next time use `code` blocks instead of `blockquote` and you'll be ok.